# htaccess redirect throws an error: PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: htaccess, errors, rewrite-rules

Using the `.htaccess`, I want to 301 redirect all the requests that end with `default.aspx` to the version without it. Like:

```
https://example.com/pagename/default.aspx
```

will be redirected to

```
https://example.com/pagename/
```

So I use the following `rewriteRule` but it is throwing a 500 error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/default\.aspx$ $1 [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
```

The error is:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /site/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1248
```

And the related part in kses.php is:

```
function wp_kses_no_null( $string, $options = null ) {
    if ( ! isset( $options['slash_zero'] ) ) {
        $options = array( 'slash_zero' => 'remove' );
    }

    $string = preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/', '', $string ); // line 1248
    if ( 'remove' == $options['slash_zero'] ) {
        $string = preg_replace( '/\\\\+0+/', '', $string );
    }

    return $string;
}
```

I do not see how the rewrite rule and this error is connected. And would like to know if it is possible to make such a redirect.

Thank you.

Comment: the 500 error come only from the rewrite rule. look in the error log of Apache and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't really connected. It's just a redirect after all.

The error means that some code in your website wrongly passes a `WP_Error` object to `wp_kses_no_null()`. In your position I'd put something like this into this function for debugging:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $string ) ) {
  var_dump( $string );
  debug_print_backtrace();
}
```

This way you can see exactly what the error is and where it's coming from. Maybe it's the fault of a plugin or theme, or some misconfiguration.